# I can't figure out any other possible reason. can you help me?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

When I integrate the HMS Core SDK into my app or game, result code 6003 is
always returned during an API call.  The official document indicates that this fault is caused by an incorrect signing certificate fingerprint. But I have checked that the app's certificate signature is the same as that configured in AppGallery Connect.

[Official document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/error-code-0000001050045846-V5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Ensure that the app's certificate signature is the same as that configured in AppGallery Connect.

1. Open the APK file of the app, extract the META-INF directory from the file, obtain the CERT.RSA file in the directory, and run the keytool -printcert -file META-INF/CERT.RSA command to display the signature certificate information.
2. Check the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint configured in AppGallery Connect by referring to Configuring the Signing Certificate Fingerprint. If the information is the same as the preceding information displayed, the certificate fingerprint is correct.
   [image]

Step 2: Ensure that the appid parameter in the manifest file is correct.
You can perform the check in either of the following ways:
•   View the parameter directly in the manifest file under the project.
•   Decompile the packaged APK file, and view the parameter. You can use any decompliation tool for that.

Step 3: Check whether the app is hardened or re-signed.
Since AppGallery Connect does not re-sign an app currently, you need to locate the fault if your app has been hardened or re-signed by yourself.

Step 4: Check whether HUAWEI App Signing is enabled.
Huawei provides the App Signing service for developers to let Huawei host their app's signature key and use it for the APK file to be distributed.
According to the official document, if the service is enabled, the generated certificate fingerprint must be added in AppGallery Connect.
[image]